# errors when trying to compile a child class in Java

Tags: java, compiler-errors

Hi I am trying to compile a child class, Car.java that extends the abstract class Vehicle.java and also implements the interface Comparable.

I am getting the following errors when I try to compile the Car.java class:

Car is not abstract and does not override Abstract Method get PassengerCapacity() in Vehicle,
cannot find symbol 
and
Missing Method body, or declare Abstract

What do I look for to rectify it?

The Car.java class extends the Abstact class vehicle and also implements the Comparable interface

ie:
 public class Car extends Vehicle implements Comparable

I have to write 2 classes Car.java and Bus.java. They both Extend Vehicle and Implement Comparable.

Everything needs to work for me to run the programs selectionSort.java and SortVehicle.java.

These errors are preventing me from completing my class Car.java as I cannot get past them to then be able to write the Bus.java class and then run the SortSelection.java and SortVehicle.java programs.

Vehicle.java, SelectionSort.java and SortVehicle.java have been supplied to me without any errors or issues.

I would be grateful for any help in rectifying these errors.

My Car.java Code is:

```
public class Car extends Vehicle implements Comparable
{
public static final int MAX_ENGINE_CAPACITY = 2000;
public static final int MIN_ENGINE_CAPACITY = 1800;
public static final int MAX_NUMBER_OF_SEATS = 7;
public static final int MIN_NUMBER_OF_SEATS = 7;

private String vehicleColour;
private int numberOfSeats;
private int engineCapacity;

public Car (Car otherCar)
{
    super();
    this.vehicleColour = otherCar.vehicleColour;
    this.numberOfSeats = otherCar.numberOfSeats;        
    this.engineCapacity = otherCar.engineCapacity;
}   

/public Car()
{
    super();
    this.vehicleColour = new vehicleColour();
    this.numberOfSeats = MIN_NUMBER_OF_SEATS;
    this.engineCapacity = MIN_ENGINE_CAPACITY;
}

public Car (String aModel, int aYearOfManufacture, String aVehicleColour, int aNumberOfSeats, int aEngineCapacity)
{
    super(aModel, aYearOfManufacture);
    this.vehicleColour = otherCar.vehicleColour;
    this.numberOfSeats = otherCar.numberOfSeats;        
    this.engineCapacity = otherCar.engineCapacity;
}


public String getVehicleColour()
    {
    return this.vehicleColour;
    }

public int getNumberOfSeats()
    {
    return this.numberOfSeats;
    }

public int getEngineCapacity()
    {
    return this.engineCapacity;
    }
public void setVehicleColour (String newVehicleColour);
    {
        if (newVehicleColour == null)
        {
            System.out.println("Fatal Error setting vehicle colour.");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        else
            this.vehiclColour = newVehicleColour;
    }

public void  setNumberOfSeats (int newNumberOfSeats)
    {
    if (newNumberOfSeats == null)
        {
         System.out.println("Fatal Error setting number Of Seats.");
         System.exit(0);
        }
   else
        this.numberOfSeats = newNumberOfSeats;
    }

 public void  setEngineCapacity (int newEngineCapacity);
   {
    if (newEngineCapacity == null)
        {
         System.out.println("Fatal Error setting number Of Seats.");
         System.exit(0);
        }
   else
        this.engineCapacity = newEngineCapacity;
    }
```

}

And the Vehicle.java code is:

```
public abstract class Vehicle
{
public static final int MAX_REASONABLE_YEAR_OF_MANUFACTURE = 2100;
public static final int MIN_REASONABLE_YEAR_OF_MANUFACTURE = 1000;

private String model;
private int yearOfManufacture;

public Vehicle ()
{
    this.model = "(model unspecified)";
    this.yearOfManufacture = MIN_REASONABLE_YEAR_OF_MANUFACTURE;
}

public Vehicle (String aModel, int aYearOfManufacture)
{
    this.model = aModel;
    if (yearOfManufactureReasonable(aYearOfManufacture))
        this.yearOfManufacture = aYearOfManufacture;
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Fatal Error: unreasonable year of manufacture used defining vehicle.");
        System.exit(0);
    }
}

public Vehicle (Vehicle otherVehicle)
{
    this.model = otherVehicle.model;
    this.yearOfManufacture = otherVehicle.yearOfManufacture;
}

private static boolean yearOfManufactureReasonable(int aYearOfManufacture)
{
    return (aYearOfManufacture >= MIN_REASONABLE_YEAR_OF_MANUFACTURE 
             && aYearOfManufacture <= MAX_REASONABLE_YEAR_OF_MANUFACTURE);
}

public String getModel ()
{
    return this.model;
}

public int getYearOfManufacture ()
{
    return this.yearOfManufacture;
}

public void setModel (String aModel)
{
    this.model = aModel;
}

public void setYearOfManufacture (int aYearOfManufacture)
{
    if (yearOfManufactureReasonable(aYearOfManufacture))
        this.yearOfManufacture = aYearOfManufacture;
}

public String toString ()
{
    return (this.model + ", " + this.yearOfManufacture);
}

public boolean equals (Object otherObject)
{
    if (otherObject == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != otherObject.getClass())
        return false;
    Vehicle otherVehicle = (Vehicle)otherObject;
    return (this.model.equals(otherVehicle.model) 
             && this.yearOfManufacture == otherVehicle.yearOfManufacture);
}

public abstract int getPassengerCapacity ();

public boolean greaterPassengerCapacityThan (Vehicle otherVehicle)
{
    return (this.getPassengerCapacity() > otherVehicle.getPassengerCapacity());
}
```

}

the full list of errors I get are as follows:

```
    Car.java:5: error: Car is not abstract and does not override abstract method get
    PassengerCapacity() in Vehicle
    public class Car extends Vehicle implements Comparable
           ^
    Car.java:27: error: cannot find symbol
            this.vehicleColour = new vehicleColour();
                                                         ^
    symbol:   class vehicleColour
    location: class Car
    Car.java:35: error: cannot find symbol
    this.vehicleColour = otherCar.vehicleColour;
                                        ^
    symbol:   variable otherCar
    location: class Car
    Car.java:36: error: cannot find symbol
            this.numberOfSeats = otherCar.numberOfSeats;
                                                    ^
    symbol:   variable otherCar
    location: class Car
    Car.java:37: error: cannot find symbol
            this.engineCapacity = otherCar.engineCapacity;
                                                    ^
    symbol:   variable otherCar
    location: class Car
    Car.java:56: error: missing method body, or declare abstract
    public void setVehicleColour (String newVehicleColour);
                   ^
    Car.java:58: error: cannot find symbol
                    if (newVehicleColour == null)
                         ^
    symbol:   variable newVehicleColour
    location: class Car
    Car.java:64: error: cannot find symbol
                            this.vehiclColour = newVehicleColour;
                                  ^
    symbol: variable vehiclColour
    Car.java:64: error: cannot find symbol
                            this.vehiclColour = newVehicleColour;
                                                              ^
   symbol:   variable newVehicleColour
   location: class Car
   Car.java:69: error: incomparable types: int and <null>
    if (newNumberOfSeats == null)
                                              ^
   Car.java:78: error: missing method body, or declare abstract
   public void  setEngineCapacity (int newEngineCapacity);
                       ^
   Car.java:80: error: cannot find symbol
    if (newEngineCapacity == null)
         ^
   symbol:   variable newEngineCapacity
   location: class Car
   Car.java:86: error: cannot find symbol
        this.engineCapacity = newEngineCapacity;
                                                ^
   symbol:   variable newEngineCapacity
   location: class Car
   13 errors
```

Comment: Show your abstract and concrete class code

Comment: @user3074723 you need to put your code in your question. Also make sure to explain it properly.

Comment: KevinDTimms I have added my code to my question with the errors list from the compiler.

Comment: @KevinDTimms I have added my code to my question with the errors list from the compiler

Answer (score 2):

You have to implement `getPassengerCapacity()` method in your `Car` class or Mark your `Car` class as `abstract`. You cannot extend an abstract class and leave a method without implementing the body. If you don't want to implement that method, then this class needs to be marked as `abstract` as well.

Answer (score 0):

your error message states that your class Car must implement the abstract method PassengerCapacity() defined in Vehicle. If you think you've done it may be you just  mistyped a keyword in the signature of the method ?

Answer (score 0):

The existing answers are good - but just to add, if you use the @override annotation where you implement the abstract methods then you will immediately get an error at that point if you get something wrong in the method signature.